# WMCI - how to get the ERRORLEVEL

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to use the "wmic" command for finding out if a specific java process is still up and running.

E.g.> wmic process where "commandLine like '%ACTMonitor%' and executablePath like '%PATH1%' and name like '%java%'"

The problem now is that the errorlevel of this command is always 0, no matter if there is a process listed or not. How can I manage to get an errorlevel != 0 in case the process is not up anymore?
Or can one of you tell me another suggestion on how to be able to continue in a .bat script with this information...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

In general, in a batch file, you can use the `FIND` command to check whether you get specific output from a command:

```
>ECHO This is correct | FIND "correct" > NUL
>ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
0
>ECHO This is bad | FIND "correct" > NUL
1
```

Does that help?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for this fast response. Yes, you are right, I did exactly the same thing in my script - but then I found out that it's possible to make restrictions in the wmic command (using like...) itself - and this seems more clear to me.

So there is no solution to do it the other way, only as suggested:

wmic process get executablePath,commandLine | find /i "java" | find /i "%ACTMonitor%" | find /i "%PATH1%" >NUL ??

Comment: There doesn't seem to be, as far as I can tell... I would actually use the `wmic` command that you suggested in the question, but use `find` on the result of that - so instead of having to do 3 `find` commands, you just have one `wmic` and one `find`. This has the advantage that `wmic` doesn't end up piping information about every single process just so that `find` can filter it out - let `wmic` do the filtering, just use `find` to convert that to a yes/no at the end...

Comment: Ok, I will do that. Just one more question, is there a way of combining an "and" into one for? Like at the moment I have these three pipes in series and would like to have one saying "find "java and %ACTMonitor% and %PATH%"?

Comment: Why do you need to? Just put the "and" into the "wmic" command! For example: `wmic process where "commandLine like '%ACTMonitor%' and executablePath like '%PATH1%' and name like '%java%'" GET HANDLE /VALUE | FIND Handle=`